# Making different size of `radius` to create `arc` not working

Tags: d3.js, svg

I am creating `pie` chart using `d3.js`. I would like to create 3 pies with single `svg` element with animation.

This is working fine for me. But do creating different I am reducing the `radius` each time using a loop. But the `radius` not getting changed.
How to solve this?

my code (sample) :

```
var array1 = [

  0,200

]

window.onload = function () {

  var width = 660,
    height = 200,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var arc = null;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function(d) { 
      return d; })
    .sort(null);

 function tweenPie(finish) {


    var start = {
            startAngle: 0,
            endAngle: 0
        };
    var i = d3.interpolate(start, finish);
    return function(d) { return arc(i(d)); };
}

var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);



  for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

    arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(radius - (5*i)) //each time size differs
    .outerRadius(radius - (6)*i); //each time size differs

      svg1.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
      .datum(array1).selectAll("path")
      .data(pie) 
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
      .transition()
      .duration(5000)
      .attrTween('d', tweenPie)

  }

}
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5R47mtKKMXdM9EC9cPE?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single arc variable that is being used in the tweenPie method and in the for loop.  Each time through the for loop, the arc variable is set to a new value. The tweenPie method is called for each pie chart after the for loop exits. As a result, all the pie charts are using the same tweenPie method which is using the arc created in the last for loop.

For each pie chart, you need to create a separate tweenPie method with its own arc. For example...

```
var array1 = [ 0, 200 ]

window.onload = function () {

    var width = 660,
        height = 200,
        radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

    var color = d3.scale.category20();

    var arc = null;

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
        .value(function(d) { 
            return d; })
        .sort(null);

    function getTweenPie(arc) {
        return function (finish) {
            var start = {
                startAngle: 0,
                endAngle: 0
            };
            var i = d3.interpolate(start, finish);
            return function(d) { return arc(i(d)); };
        }
    }

    var svg1 = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    for( var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

        arc = d3.svg.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius - (5*i)) //each time size differs
            .outerRadius(radius - (6)*i); //each time size differs

        svg1.append('g')
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
            .datum(array1).selectAll("path")
            .data(pie) 
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
            .transition()
            .duration(5000)
            .attrTween('d', getTweenPie(arc))

    }

}
```

Comment: can you have a look here? instead of getting multiple arc, i am getting only one http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/7458/

Comment: In this jsfiddle example, you are creating a single arc object. During the initial drawing, you are changing the inner and out radius as each value is rendered. But the tween methods are leaving the inner and out radius unchanged. As a result, all the tween methods are using the same arc object which has the inner and outer radius of the last pie chart.

Comment: so, what is the correct way to get it done? can you help me to sort this out?